# select data using link table in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have link table and table. Link table will have 2 records of data one is 'Region' and another is 'Sub-Region' and actual table also has 2 records for 'Region' and 'Sub-Region'. I want get as single record using link

I think example will explain more what I am looking for

### Event_Region

```
EventID | RegionID | RegionType_Code
1         1          SSam
1         2          SRUSA
```

### Region

```
RegionID | RegionType_Code | Region_Name
1          SSam               Americas
2          SRUSA              USA
```

### Output

```
EventID| Region    | Sub-Region
1        Americas    USA
```

Region always starts `SS` and Sub-Region starts with `SR`

How can get output this way?

### Update

Whats wrong here?

```
SELECT      e.EventId,
            e.Event_Code AS Code,
            e.Event_Type_Description AS [Event],                
            e.Event_Name as Name,               
            max(case when left(er.RegionType_Code, 2) = 'SS' then r.region_name end) Region,
            max(case when left(er.RegionType_Code, 2) = 'SR' then r.region_name end) SubRegion      

FROM         dbo.Event e                 
             INNER JOIN Event_Region er ON er.EventId = e.EventId
             INNER JOIN Region r ON r.RegionId = er.RegionId 
group by e.EventId;
```

I am getting error

`Column 'dbo.Event.Event_Code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: But I am going to add more tables and fields to this query. I cannot add them to group by clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use an aggregate function with a `CASE`:

```
select er.eventid,
  max(case when left(er.RegionType_Code, 2) = 'SS' then r.region_name end) Region,
  max(case when left(er.RegionType_Code, 2) = 'SR' then r.region_name end) SubRegion
from Event_Region er
inner join Region r
  on er.regionid = r.regionid
group by er.eventid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1658c/8)